# AclPermissionsFacet fault install SQL-2008-R2

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, sql-server-2008

While attempting to do an installation repair of SQL-2008R2, I'm failing the pre-check rules.

Module that is failing is AclPermissionsFacet  - with this message "*The SQL Server registry keys from a prior installation cannot be modified. To continue, see SQL Server Setup documentation about how to fix registry keys*."

In the log file "Detail_GlobalRules.txt", I've been able to find the following error messages -

- 2010-09-05 07:24:39 Slp: Could not
  open sub key key
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
  Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSearch.
- 2010-09-05 07:24:39 Slp: Could not
  open sub key key
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
  Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\SQLServerSCP.
- 2010-09-05 07:24:39 Slp: Could not
  open sub key key
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
  Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer.
- 2010-09-05 07:24:39 Slp: Could not
  open sub key key
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL
  Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\SQLServerAgent.

When I look at these keys in the registry, all of their permissions are blank.  My problem is that I cannot find any good information on how to reset these keys.  This is on my new home dev and I think during the migration from my previous machine, these settings got corrupted on my new box.  In reviewing the web, there doesn't seem to be good infomration.  And what there is suggests using subinacl.exe.  But after trying it and seeing it is an XP based program, I'm at a loss on how to continue.

Configuration - Windows 7/64bit Home Edition, SQL2008R2, 6gb ram.

Suggestions?

Su

Answer (score 0):

Try what I did. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/fdb33ba1-a67a-4cd7-bccb-90ac07a43e1c

> 1. Located **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft** SQL Server in registry
> 2. Right click and go to **Permission**
> 3. Click on **Advance**
> 4. Tick on both check box (I. Inherit from parent the permission... II. Replace permission entries on all child objects...), click **OK**
> 5. Click **OK** again

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had an older version of SQL Server running (2000 Desktop Engine) which I needed to keep running.

The solution was to stop the service during installation of SQL Server 2008.